# How to Copy File and Folder permissions but not folders and files?

Tags: windows, xcopy

I have two copies of same folder in windows. but the permissions of one of them are missing.
How can I copy permissions of the original source to other?
I know I can use the xcopy command but the data is big and if I use xcopy I should waste much time.
whats your advise?

Comment: If one is simply a copy of the other what is the reason you can't simply delete one and start over with a new copy of the other one, or am I missing something?

Comment: you can simply say I don't know.to copy that folder you should spend 5 hours. Is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

You could use icacls to first enumerate all permissions and then re-apply them:

To save:

```
icacls [your_source_path]\* /save aclfile /t
```

To restore (re-apply)

```
icacls [your_destination_path]\ /restore aclfile
```

Reference, examples taken and modified from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx

Comment: Oh, I have fallen in the trap! (old question). I will leave it here, maybe someone will find this useful...

Answer (score 0):

I think just use windows explorer (the graphical interface) to delete, then cut and paste to make the new copy.  Then go do something else while you wait.  Let the computer do the work for you.

By the way, when you do the delete it will ask you to permanently delete because of the large size of what you are requesting to delete.  Answer yes.  (If you delete and it goes to your garbage can it is much slower.)

Messing around with the old xcopy is not what I would be doing if I were you.

Comment: and what about permissions?